# SQL Join and result filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the northwind database and trying to find pairs of products that were never ordered.

I can easily get all the possible product pairs with a simple

```
select p1.ProductName, p2.ProductName
    FROM products p1 CROSS JOIN products p2
```

And it neatly returns all possible combinations (5'929, to be precise).

To get all product pairs from the order details I need to join a few tables, but a

```
select DISTINCT p3.ProductName, p4.ProductName
    FROM order_details od1
    JOIN products p3
    ON od1.ProductID = p3.ProductID
    CROSS JOIN order_details od2
    ON od1.OrderId = od2.OrderID
    JOIN products p4
    ON od2.ProductId = p4.productid
```

Does the trick and returns 3'147 combinations.

The problem is when I try to actually subtract the second query result from the first. No matter what `join` or `where` i use, i always get about 18 million records. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: buy subtract you mean where not in right!?

Comment: Is the final resultset giving you every combination of the first query joined with the second query? 5,929 * 3,147 = 18,656,563 so that would account for why you are getting ~18m records. What are you using to combine the queries, it seems like a JOIN, where as you should probably be using a NOT IN.

Comment: The problem is that i need to compare pairs. Is `not in` capable of doing that?

Comment: Your query to "find all the products that were never ordered" is just wrong. A cross join will get you all possible combination of products that you could possibly ever have. You need to do a LEFT JOIN (or RIGHT) to figure this out.

Comment: I think you got that a bit wrong. I want to find pairs of products that were never ordered together.

Comment: @Dashy Can you provide your table schema please. I might be able to write this query for you.

Comment: Northwind is a sample database provided by microsoft. Anyway, here's a link: http://merc.tv/img/fig/Northwind_diagram.jpg

Comment: Ok so to clarify what you need here, you want to know all products that were never purchased correct?

Comment: Almost. What I need are pairs of products that were never purchased together in a single order. It's basically a cross join of all products minus cross joins of products of every order. (I think)

Comment: Um, that's not a CROSS JOIN !!!!

Comment: This gets complicated as an order can have any number of products. For example if one order has 10 products and another has 5? What would you consider a pair here? What would your expected result be here?

For example, order 1 has product id 1,2,3,4,9 and thus 9 has been paired with orders 1,2,3,4 and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what your after

EDIT: This only works for MySQL. Didn't see OP mention Northwind in the comments.

```
SELECT p1.ProductName, p2.ProductName
FROM products p1
CROSS JOIN products p2
WHERE (p1.ProductName, p2.ProductName) NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT p3.ProductName, p4.ProductName
    FROM order_details od1
    JOIN products p3
    ON od1.ProductID = p3.ProductID
    CROSS JOIN order_details od2
    ON od1.OrderId = od2.OrderID
    JOIN products p4
    ON od2.ProductId = p4.productid
)
```

Should return you 2,782 results

Comment: Like mySQL (and Oracle) type of NOT IN() syntax. However, please note that this will not work in SQL Server. The mention of Nothwind database makes me suspect that OP is actually running the queries in SQL Server

Comment: True. Only just noticed mention of Northwind after I had posted this. I don't know if there is any equivalent for SQL Server.